# Can't log in to Github via VS Code (HSTS Security issue)

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, security, hsts

I am trying to log into my Github account via VS Code, and I encountered the following error VSCode attempts to open a login window in the browser:

> Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to vscode.dev because this website requires a secure connection.
>
> What can you do about it?
>
> vscode.dev has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.

When I am prompted to log in to Github in VS Code and I click to open the login window, the error is raised, and the URL in the browser bar is https://vscode.dev/. I have tried opening the window in multiple browsers, but I'm encountering the same issue in each one. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Comment: Are you trying `http://vscode.dev` or `https://vscode.dev`?

Comment: @JimRedmond Updated the post to indicate that the login window is attempting to load `https://vscode.dev/`.